# How to make object with fixed positioning move from top of my browser window to the bottom as I scroll down my website?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a website that is 6 times the height of my browser window. I Want to have an image with fixed positioning move from the top of the browser window to the bottom as I scroll from the top of my website to the bottom.

Id give you some example code but i'm totally stuck with this and don't even know where to start.

Im just looking for a very simple example. Im limited to html5, css and jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zolLe

```
$( ".scroll__inner" ).click( function(){
    console.log("this1");
    window.scrollBy(0,600); 
});
```

In this i added one on click event for scroll down and all others are same as @ckuijjer answer. I used scroll by function to scroll down. You can also scroll to bottom directly by giving height to scrollby.

Answer (score 2):

You need to know how large the document is `var documentHeight = $(document).height()`, how large the screen is `var screenHeight = $(window).height()` and how far the user has scrolled `var scrollAmount = $(window).scrollTop`.

Calculate the maximum amount that can be scrolled `var maxScrollAmount = documentHeight - windowHeight` and use that to determine what part of the page has already been seen (a number between zero and one) `var amountSeen = scrollAmount / maxScrollAmount`. If you multiply that by the size of the window you know how far the `top` of your image should be `var top = amountSeen * windowHeight`

I've started on a small jQuery plugin that you can extend, see http://codepen.io/ckuijjer/pen/lGqAs . It doesn't support resizing of the document, and it isn't optimized but it's a start.

Comment: hmm, that isnt going to work, it needs to support re sizing. Does it help at all that the website is broken down in to 6 height:100% sections?

Comment: That's why it's a start :) I've added resizing functionality. If you want to use this in production I suggest understanding and optimizing it, for example does it really need to set the position on every scroll event?

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of what you're moving, the main thing you'll need is the scroll position of the browser window as a percentage. This requires a little calculation, as scroll position is only provided by the browser as the number of pixels above the top of the screen:

```
// Vanilla Javascript
var scrollPercent = document.body.scrollTop / (document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight);

// JQuery
var scrollPercent = $(window).scrollTop() / ($(document.body).height() - $(window).height());
```

Once you have the scroll position in percent form, you can use that to set the `top` property of your fixed element to position it in the window: `scrollPercent * window.height`.

[Here's a JSFiddle that demonstrates this.](http://jsfiddle.net/ptkb9Lr1/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want have an Image that in all scroll position display on whole windows, in your image tag put this style:

```
<img id="img1" src="" style="position:fixed; top=0; left=o; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:-10;" />

$(function(){
    $("#img1").css({"height": $(document.height()) + "px", "width": $(document.width()) + "px"});
});
```

Comment: This isnt exactly what im looking for. This pretty much just sets the image to fixed positioning. What im looking for is a way to make the image go from the top of the browser window as you scroll to represent how far down the page you are.